# Convert value in R in multi column

Tags: r, csv

I have 2 csv file which the data is look like which run the same R File, I have hundreds of rows and column to run with, I wish to convert the 1 = Enroll, 0 = Quit, " " = No data:

```
Test <- read.csv("..\\..\TestFile.csv", colClasses = "factor")
[1] [2] [3] 
1   0             
0   1
1   1
1   0   1

[1] [2] [3] 
1   0             
1   1
1   0
1   0   1

So, far I had tried on 

revalue(Test$1, c("1" = "Enroll")) -> Test$1
revalue(Test$1, c("0" = "Quit")) -> Test$1
revalue(Test$2, c("1" = "Enroll")) -> Test$2
revalue(Test$2, c("0" = "Quit")) -> Test$2
revalue(Test$3, c("1" = "Enroll")) -> Test$3
revalue(Test$3, c("0" = "Quit")) -> Test$3

write.csv(Test, "TestFile.csv", na = "No data")

But, it promt the warning msg: The following `from` values were not present in `x`: 1.
The NA string unable to update to "No data". Please help.
```

Answer (score 1):

I. Created dataframe `df` with `1` , `0` and `NA`

```
    df <- data.frame(Col1 = c(1,0,0,1), Col2 = c(0,0,0,1), Col3 = c(1,NA,0,NA))
    df
    #   Col1 Col2 Col3
    # 1    1    0    1
    # 2    0    0   NA
    # 3    0    0    0
    # 4    1    1   NA
```

II. Substituting specific values

```
    df[df == 0] <- "Quit" 
    df[df == 1] <- "Enroll" 
    df[is.na(df)] <- "No Data"
```

III. Final `df`

```
    df
    #     Col1   Col2    Col3
    # 1 Enroll   Quit  Enroll
    # 2   Quit   Quit No Data
    # 3   Quit   Quit    Quit
    # 4 Enroll Enroll No Data
```

OR

```
   c(df[is.na(df)] <- "No Data" , df[df == 0] <- "Quit", df[df == 1] <- "Enroll")
   # [1] "No Data" "Quit"    "Enroll" 

   df
   #     Col1   Col2    Col3
   # 1 Enroll   Quit  Enroll
   # 2   Quit   Quit No Data
   # 3   Quit   Quit    Quit
   # 4 Enroll Enroll No Data
```

Comment: When I was substituting specific value, it prompt the warning message 
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "Quit") :  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: Please show you actual command from which you got this error. May be then it would be better to understand.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` to change the values in each of the columns

```
Test[] <- lapply(Test, function(x) {x1 <- c("Quit", "Enroll")[x+1]
                     replace(x1, is.na(x1), "No Data")})
Test
#    Col1   Col2    Col3
#1 Enroll   Quit  Enroll
#2   Quit   Quit No Data
#3   Quit   Quit    Quit
#4 Enroll Enroll No Data
```

---

If we have hundreds of columns, another approach is `mutate_each` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
Test %<>%
      mutate_each(funs(c("Quit", "Enroll")[.+1])) %<>% 
      mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), "No Data")))
```

Comment: I had try the Test[] <- lapply(Test, function(x) ifelse(x==0, "Enroll", "Quit")), nut my NA value become Quit, instead of I wannated the NA value replace as No data

Comment: @akrun A new thing for me is `%<>%` , let me check what it does. Thank you.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  It will change the values in 'Test' in place.  So, we don't need to assign it to `Test <- Test %>% ...`

Comment: Oh so even if it is updated, it would use the updated one and then apply the functions mentioned next?

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  If you check the output of 'Test', it will be different